# Error thrown while trying to match a pattern in a node text

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML line.

```
<para><content-style font-style="italic">Schedule 14.2</content-style></para>
<para><content-style font-style="bold">14.45 Schedule</content-style></para>
```

I was trying to get the match for second `para` given above using the below XSLT.

```
    <xsl:when test="fn:contains(./content-style[1],'.') and fn:not(fn:contains(substring-before(./content-style[1]/text(),' '),text()))">
```

but here it is throwing me an error. And the error is,

```
Wrong occurrence to match required sequence type -   Details: -     XPTY0004: The supplied sequence ('2' item(s)) has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:string ('zero or one')
```

what i was basically trying to match is,

```
Check if there is a `.` in the `content-style` and 
then check if there is any text() preceding space before the number
```

also i would like to know the difference between `node()` and `node()/text()` and also between `self::node()` and `./node() or child::node()`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, you've shown your XML as this..

```
<para><content-style font-style="italic">Schedule 14.2</content-style></para>
<para><content-style font-style="bold">14.45 Schedule</content-style></para>
```

When, perhaps, it looks like this:

```
<root>
    <para>
        <content-style font-style="italic">Schedule 14.2</content-style>
    </para>
    <para>
        <content-style font-style="bold">14.45 Schedule</content-style>
    </para>
</root>
```

You might not think there is any difference, but there is. In the second example, there are text nodes (containing white-space) before and after the **content-style** elements under each **para**. It is significant, because this is the part of the condition that is affected

```
not(contains(substring-before(./content-style[1]/text(),' '),text()))
```

You can probably see it better, if you simplify it (just for example's sake) to this, as the substring-before is not the issue in this case

```
 <xsl:value-of select="not(contains('Schedule',text()))" />
```

Here, `text()` gets 'text' nodes under the current node. In this case, under the **para** element. It is not checking if a string contains text, but whether the string contains the value of the text node. But you have two text nodes, hence the error.

I couldn't quite following your logic as to what you want, but maybe you want to check if the bit before the space is a number or not. In which case, you would do this (to check if it is text, and not a number)

```
 <xsl:value-of select="string(number('Schedule')) = 'NaN'" />
```

Or, with the substring-before put back in, to make it relevant to the **para** element

```
 <xsl:value-of select="string(number(substring-before(./content-style[1]/text(),' '))) = 'NaN'" />
```

Remember, expressions like `text()` and `node()` are relative to the current node. `self::node()`, which is equivalent to just `.` will get the current node, but `./node()` or `child::node()` (or just `node()`) will get child nodes.

Doing `text()` will get child nodes which happen to be text nodes.

Comment: Thanks @TimC, this is pretty clear now. Thanks again for explaining me this.